# Can't move from one JSP to another

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

At the beginning I'm at `adminPage.jsp` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>System Administrator Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
<h1>
Please choose one of the following options
</h1>



<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new manager to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAddNewManager"> 
    <a href="registration.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

And I want to move to `registration.jsp` , which is located at the same folder of `adminPage.jsp` .

But when I try to move to `adminPage.jsp`  :

[image]

I get :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WebBank/registration.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /WebBank/registration.jsp

description The requested resource (/WebBank/registration.jsp) is not available.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
```

Why is that ?

Regards

Comment: Paste the URL displayed in the address bar of your browser before clicking on the link. Do the same after clicking on the link. And show us the file tree structure of the webapp.

Comment: when you go to the admin.jsp, what is the url in the browser?

Comment: and where this is located in your project?

Comment: Put the entire path of the jsp page, not only the name of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It's in the same folder, use `< a href="/registration.jsp">Press here to continue< /a>`

If it didn't help (which I doubt):
`HTTP Status 404` means that the requested file could not be found on the server (not surprisingly)
So either of these are happening:

1. The URL is incorrect. (I'd bet on this).
2. The file **is not created** or **has different name** or **is not saved**.

   You might also want to check that the page name is all in lowercase or is exactly `registration.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

First of all i think the form tag is useless you're calling a new page using a link not the form so u could simply remove it.

Second in your href try to put ./registration.jsp